# Practise questions for oracle database

Tags: oracle

Hey Friends I have read concepts of database and tried it to do that on home . But i want some kind of practise questions on database. Can u tell me any source from where can i get practise questions for sql and pl/sql. ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PL/SQL Challenge site might be a good source

http://www.plsqlchallenge.com/

Comment: +1, also it will soon be getting an upgrade where they will be offering SQL questions as well as PL/SQL questions.